# ASP.NET WebForms: Format texts for strong typed ListView fields

Tags: asp.net

I tha the following markup:

```
<asp:ListView ItemType="MyNamespace.MyEntity" runat="server" >
    <listiview tags>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDebtAmount" runat="server" Text="<%#:string.Format("
            {0:C}",Item.Amount) %>"
    </listiview tags>
</asp:ListView>
```

In the given example i'm trying to apply currency format to the text rendered by a label, but i'm after achieve this for text controls in general (Labels, Literal, Textbox, etc) . The problem is that the above produce the following server error:

> "Analizer Error Mesage: Invalid Server Tag"

The same result if i try with the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDebtAmount" runat="server" Text="<%#:string.Format("
    {0:C}",Item.Amount.ToString("C")) %>"
```

Another approach, this time i get runtime exception:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval(Item.Amount.ToString() )) %>
```

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies... does not contains a
>   property named '500000,00'.

Another approach that i have tryied is formating the entity's property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

That does not produce any error but neither got the text formated, the label just render the value without format

The only thing that seems to work is using the old way databinding:

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Amount")) %>
```

But if i'm going to use strong typed binding for Webforms i dont want to be using strings to resolve properties value anymore:
I think this has to be dead easy, any thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching from double quotes to single quotes for the text property, the way you currently have it ends the string early so the text property is actually just `"<%#:string.Format("`

```
<asp:ListView ItemType="MyNamespace.MyEntity" runat="server" >
    <listiview tags>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDebtAmount" runat="server" Text='<%#:string.Format("
            {0:C}",Item.Amount) %>'
    </listiview tags>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: So simple like that. Thanks